# PHP move_uploaded_file failing for unknown reason

Tags: php, file-io, upload

I have an PHP website on a RHEL5/CentOS dedicated server. The website is located at /var/www/html/beta

I have a script:

```
/var/www/html/beta/scriptA.php
```

which calls a function in

```
/var/www/html/beta/code/inc/functions.php
```

The function uses move_uploaded_file() as follows:

```
$status = move_uploaded_file($imagetmp_name,$destinationPath);
```

Printing these values shows:

```
imagetmp_name=/tmp/phpiECxB6
destinationPath=in_upload/images/907770756_publicpage.jpg
status=false
```

Which I thought should have worked since 'in_upload/images' exists:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Oct 19 07:40 in_upload
```

and

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Oct 19 07:40 images
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the results of `print_r($_FILES);`, especially the `error` flag? ALso, try turning on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in case it's a permission problem in the target folder

Comment: On second look, it's a permissions problem in the target folder. If I read `drwxr-xr-x` correctly, only the root user is allowed to write in it

Comment: Hey Pekka / others - should I be changing from root to apache? Do I have to do so for every folder I will be writing to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have writing permisions to `in_upload` neither `images`, only for root.

Use

```
chmod a+w in_upload
chmod a+w images
```

or change that directories' owner/group to the user, under which is apache running.
example:

```
chown apache:apache in_upload
chmod g+w in_upload
```